# Solving for $h$, given $\frac{T}{w} = h + \frac{X-1}{h^i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form

I have a problem which have happened to me before. It just takes so long between the incidents in different courses I take so I never remember how to approach the issue. I really need some way to think about how to approach this that I might actually remember.

How do I solve for a variable when the terms of it have different exponents?

In my case:

$$\frac{T}{w} = h + \frac{X-1}{h^i}$$

I need to solve for $h$. I just can't find a way to do it.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: This equation will not have a closed form solution for $h$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then I must have formulated my problem in the wrong way to begin with, because there is supposed to be a solution.

Comment: For rational $i$, your equation is an algebraic equation over $\mathbb{C}$ for $h$. For rational $i\neq 0$, the equation is a trinomial equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re arrange this, to get $h^{i+1} - \left(\frac{T}{w}\right)h^i + (X-1)=0$.

***Edit: the following only applies if $i$ is a non negative integer.***

This is a degree $i+1$ polynomial. This has closed form solutions if $i\leq3$, by the quadratic, cubic or quartic formula. However, it is a well known result of Abel, often proved via Galois theory, that there is no general formula for polynomials of degree 5 or larger.

So, if $i \geq 4$, then you may be lucky and have a closed form solutions if the coefficients happen to work nicely. However, this will not be true in general!

You could try factoring out $h^i$ which would give you $h^i(h - \frac{T}{w})= 1 - X$. This may or may not help, depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you! Having i > 1 would not make sense.

Comment: +1 This nice answer works only if $i$ is a positive integer. That's implicit in the question but not specified.

Comment: @EthanBolker absolutely, I should have made that clear!